# Forgot to tag someone in the comments

Tags: support, comments

Let's say I'm answering a comment under a question.

I write my answer, send it.

Afterwards, I realize I forgot to put `@userName` at the beginning of my comment to notify the other user I was talking to him.

If I edit my comment to add it, will he get a notification?

Comment: Let's give this a try... Someone can write a comment after Zenoo's, then edit in my name... I shouldn't be pinged for the first comment, but should be, when my name is edited in.

Comment: @Cerbrus Did you get a notification?

Comment: @Cerbrus sure...why not ?

Comment: I got pinged for that comment by @SurajRao.

Comment: @Cerbrus Alright, thanks ! That settles it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I edit my comment to add it, will he get a notification?

Yes, he will get notified.

Comment: So in theory one could edit pings to several users one after another (removing the previous pings), and send multiple notifications with a single comment?

Comment: @user000001: I'm not sure. Maybe the notification is removed when a name is removed. Maybe it won't ping anyone if you change the name...